# nginx passing non-standard http request header to php

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as the web server and php-fpm as the app server. Now I'd like to pass one or more request headers such as FROM_CLIENT : client1, what is the correct way to do it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want $_SERVER['FROM_CLIENT'] to contain 'client1', you would just add the line:

```
fastcgi_param FROM_CLIENT client1; # or use variables instead of client1 if you like
```

at the same place where you're setting your other fastcgi params or including fastcgi.conf.